# Elantech touchpad stopped working completely

Tags: touchpad, elantech

I've had this laptop for about a month and the touchpad (ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad) was working fine. Yesterday that changed. I had this weird issue with my battery where it didn't recognize that I even had a battery (acpitool said battery: "not available") and therefore it would turn off right when I unplugged the charger, as if it were a desktop computer and not a portable laptop with a rechargeable battery. Anyway, after one of these shutdowns my touchpad stopped working. Now the battery is working fine but the touchpad is not. I checked out all of the similar questions on this site but none of them worked or matched my circumstances.
Here are the details:

- No X11 cursor shows up.
- I'm running debian jessie with kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64.
- My touchpad is both recognized and enabled
- my synaptic touchpad package is fully updated
- xev shows no response from any interaction with the touchpad
- a usb mouse works, which I'm using right now
- I don't have an xorg.conf

Thanks all. I'll add anything that will help if asked. I cannot figure out what could be causing this.

```
@debian:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Mitsumi Electric Apple Optical USB Mouse  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: uname -a: Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4 (2016-02-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Your kernel is very old, and its not Ubuntu?

Comment: Questions on Debian should be asked at [unix.se].

Comment: oh, sorry. I figured it would be fine since debian and ubuntu are so similar. my kernel may be old by ubuntu standards but its the most recent kernel in use by debian stable :)

Comment: In case anyone wonders, the problem was I pressed a keyboard shortcut. I know, pitiful.